# Mismatch of alignments of fields in CSS

Tags: apex, css, html5

This may be pretty simple, but for me its like a hell. The code I tried was in both apex and html5. I want to get the fields in a proper way.I want to get state field under city and country field should be below to the State field below.
[image]

```
<div class="myclass">State<br/></div>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Objcetname__c" rendered="{!(editMode)}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!ObjectName__c}"rendered="{!NOT(editMode)}"/>
        <br/>
```

And the above Code repeats the same for all the Objects. I tried so many ways but not able to get those fields.Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: I dont know why this line is not posted in my code. This line is same for all objects(Except Object name) at the starting before apex code  :                     <div class="Test1">State<br/></div>

Comment: Any time you're posting code, select your code, then press the braces (preformatted text) button or else make certain you space in at least 4 spaces for it to display. Otherwise, the editor will hide any code that's embedded in your post. Since your question is about CSS, it would  be helpful if you posted the CSS for `myclass` along with `input` & `output` `fields`. Without it, I don't think anyone can really advise you as to what your issue is. Please use the edit button at bottom left to add your CSS to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a native Visualforce for that? It is so easy and useful!
Here is an example. I will use an `apex:panelGrid` tag. It renders an HTML table element in which each component is placed into a corresponding cell. The next component wraps to the next row and is placed in the first cell.
With `apex:panelGroup` you can group the input field and a label for example:

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="2">

    <!-- First row -->
    <apex:panelGroup>
        <span>Street</span><br/>
        <input type="text" />
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:panelGroup>
        <span>City</span><br/>
        <input type="text" />
    </apex:panelGroup>

    <!-- Second row -->
    <apex:panelGroup>
        <span>Country</span><br/>
        <input type="text" />
    </apex:panelGroup>
    <apex:panelGroup>
        <span>State</span><br/>
        <input type="text" />
    </apex:panelGroup>

</apex:panelGrid>
```

And here is a result:

[image]